# Wait for google reverse geocoding

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, google-geocoding-api

I am new with swift. For my project I need to use google geocoding and to put the result in a text. For the user interface I am using swiftUI. I tried to do the same with Completition Handler but that didn't work. Below I have the code done with DispatchQueue and DispatchGroup but the whole application freezes when I try to use this func. Please help me with this. The code for UI is just a Text calling the func.

```
func reverseGeocoding(lat: Double, lng: Double) -> String{
    
    var place:String?
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(lat),\(lng)&key=KEY"
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        AF.request(url).responseJSON{ response in
            
              //  group.leave()
            guard let data = response.data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSON(data: data)
                let result = jsonData["results"].arrayValue
                
                for result in result {
                    let address_components = result["types"].arrayValue
                    for component in address_components {
                        if(component == "locality"){
                            place = result["formatted_address"].stringValue
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    group.wait()
    return place ?? ""
}
```

Comment: Don't wait. And misusing `DispatchGroup` to make the network request synchronous is wrong, too. The completion handler is the recommended way. What issues do you have?

Comment: How can I make a Text view with completion Handler. I tried but it didnt work. Can you tell me how to put the result in the Text view with completion handler

Comment: Is this UI constructed in UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: its constructed for SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

continuation for @vadian answer 
As mentioned  in the above publisher depends on context .This will give you a rough idea.This is from what I understood..

```
// Replace String with [String] if you want to add multiple locations at once based on it Publisher.send() accepts [String] instead of String
var LocationPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
class Subscriber :ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentLocation :[String] = Array<String>()
    private var cancellebels  = Set< AnyCancellable>()
    func createSubscriber(){
        let subscriber = LocationPublisher.handleEvents(
            receiveSubscription: {subscription in
                print("New subscription \(subscription)")},
            receiveOutput: {output in
                print("New Output  \(output)")
            },
            receiveCancel: {
                print("Subscription Canceled")
            })
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            // if you replace String with [String],TypeOf(value) becomes [String]
            .sink{value in
                print("Subscriber recieved value \(value)")
                self.currentLocation.append(value)
            // use self.currenLocation.append(contentsOf:value) instead
            }

            .store(in: &cancellebels)
        
        
    }
    init() {
       createSubscriber()
    }
}
```

And inside this contentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject  var locationObject:Subscriber = Subscriber()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
    
         List{
             locationObject.currentLocation.forEach{ location in
                       Text(location)
             }
         }


        }
    }
}
```

and from the above answer inside the success completion handler use
 `LocationPublisher.send(location)`  
instead of print statement
it will be notified  to subscribers and locationObject.currentLocation will be updated 
Its just one way to do it and most basic way.

Comment: Thank you about this. But how will I use this for a List of Text?

Comment: @KIRCA I modified my answer, we can make currentLocation as Array<String> and append new location  or group of locations to the currentlocation array .Use for each in contentView to display. You can use Set<String> to discard duplicates and LazyVStack if list is to big ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me. 

Answer (score 0):

You need a completion handler like this, it returns also all errors in the `Result` type

```
enum GeoError : Error {
    case locationNoFound
}

func reverseGeocoding(lat: Double, lng: Double, completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
    
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(lat),\(lng)&key=KEY"
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        AF.request(url).responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        let jsonData = try JSON(data: data)
                        let result = jsonData["results"].arrayValue
                        
                        for result in result {
                            let addressComponents = result["types"].arrayValue
                            for component in addressComponents {
                                if component == "locality" {
                                    completion(.success(result["formatted_address"].stringValue))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        completion(.failure(GeoError.locationNoFound))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
reverseGeocoding(lat: 45.0, lng: 45.0) { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let location): print(location)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I use this to make a Text view in my SwiftUI file?

Comment: Use the `@ObservableObject` / `@Published` pattern to notify when the location is available.

Comment: Can you give me the code to do that. Since I am new to Swift I dont really know much about property wrappers. It will mean a lot because im stuck on this for 3 days.

Comment: This depends on the context. You question doesn’t contain any code related to SwiftUI.

Comment: I just need a Text view that calls this function and the result is set in the text

Comment: The function is asynchronous, you cannot call it simply, it doesn't have a return value.

Comment: Yes I know taht is asynchronous and thats tha main problem, that I need to put the result of the asunc func in a Text just to show it on  screan.

Comment: As I said use a publisher. But this depends on the context.